# How to modify telerik pageview tabs

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, telerik, pageviews

Using telerik winform pageview control how can i set the tab to be angled like the google chrome tabs.They are vertical by default. Is it an image property i need to set or a property?. I have tried the telerik forum but noone seems to have asked a similar question.

Image showing sample below

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a picture/mock up of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: hi checho - i have added a sample in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to achieve the desired effect:

```
        TabVsShape shape = new TabVsShape();
        shape.RightToLeft = true;
        foreach (RadPageViewPage p in radPageView1.Pages)
        {
            p.Item.Shape = shape;
            p.Item.MinSize = new Size(65, 0); //if you need to increase the page item size
        }
```